# Авторизация

Tags: php

кнопку *войти* нажимаю, а оно просто прогружается и опять на авторизацию перенаправляет

Если вам не понятен вопрос, то зарегистрируйтесь на тестовом сайте: http://test.bonline.16mb.com/ и попробуйте авторизоваться.

***login.php***

```
    <?php
include_once("bd.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
<title>Главаня</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $login = $_POST['login']; 
    if ($login == '') {
        unset($login);
        exit ("Введите пожалуйста логин!");
    } 
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password=$_POST['password']; 
    if ($password =='') {
        unset($password);
        exit ("Введите пароль");
    }
}

$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);

$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);

$login = trim($login);
$password = trim($password);

$password = md5($password);//шифруем пароль

$user = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password' AND activation='1'");
$id_user = mysql_fetch_array($user);
if (empty($id_user['id'])){
    exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин или пароль неверный.");
}
else {

    $_SESSION['password']=$password; 
    $_SESSION['login']=$login; 
    $_SESSION['id']=$id_user['id'];

}
echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='0; URL=index.php'>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

***index.php***

```
<?php
if(empty($login) and empty($password)){
print <<<HERE
<table>
Вход:
<br>
<br>

      <form action="login.php" method="POST">
      <tr>
      <td>Логин:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="login" ></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>Пароль:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" ></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit" ></td>
      </tr>
      </form>
      </table>
<a href="registration.php">Регистрация</a>
HERE;
}
else{
echo "Привет, <strong>".$login."</strong> | <a href='exit.php'>Выход</a><br>Контент для зарегистрированных пользователей";
}
?>
```

Comment: В коде разбираться лень, но мета рефреш в body, да с сочетанием с title - это хорошо :-)

Comment: мне вот ещё кажется, что лучше скрипт php будет положить в <head>

Comment: Уберите весь HTML для начала - он в скрипте совершенно не нужен, так как скрипт в браузер ничего не отдает. Второе - где `session_start()`? Третье - в `index.php` вообще сессия обрабатывается? Похоже что нет.

Comment: большинство написал сам, какие то обрывки например активация пароля по email

Comment: Саша, у вас не реализована сессия. Просто и понятно объясняю. Грубо говоря, ваши переменные теряются. Как не потерять - читайте http://phpfaq.ru/sessions
Подскажу: обратите внимание на `session_start()`. А дальше - читать и вникать, как записывать значения переменных в массив сессии и как оттуда их доставать на другой странице.

Comment: ладно, буду читать :D

Answer (score 1):

Ну и как `index.php` будет знать, что такое `$login`? Почитайте про сессии в `PHP` и про `Global Vars`. А вообще, мой дельный совет - не пользуйтесь чьими-то скриптами. Тем более обрывками, в которых опущены те части, на которых автор не фокусируется, надеясь на то, что использующий их знает что делает. Почитайте матчасть по теме и разберитесь как это реализуется и поймите сами.

P.S. http://phpfaq.ru/sessions